# What is wrong with DrRacket, cannot reference undefined identifier

Tags: scheme, racket

I defined a very very simple function "imap". It receives two arguments and displays the first. But see what weird thing happens:

[image: Screenshot]

The definitions are all the same things. I just change the name of arguments!
Why some forms don't work?

**implementation : drRacket of r5rs**

here is the source code.
First one is working fine:

```
> (define (imap x y) (display x))
> (imap 3 4)
3
> (imap + (list 1 2 3))
#<procedure:+>
```

Now, just change "x" to "f","y" to "x":

```
> (define (imap f x) (dislay f))
> (imap + (list 1 2 3))
. . dislay: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
```

Go on:

```
> (define (imap y x) (dislay y))
> (imap + (list 1 2 3))
. . dislay: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
```

Go on, and back to the same as the first definition:

```
> (define (imap x y) (dislay x))
> (imap + (list 1 2 3))
. . dislay: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo! you wrote `dislay`, not the correct `display`. The error message states it clearly:

```
dislay: undefined;
cannot reference undefined identifier
```

Comment: @Pythoner don't worry about it, and you're not a fool, you're just tired. Perhaps it's a good time to take a little break ;)

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Sleep is just a poor substitute for cofee ;)